# Google cloud platform: Unkown error when creating Ingress

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create an Ingress in the Google cloud platform, but when I click on the create button, I have this error that shows up:

[image]

Which means : "Error when creating an entry"

And when I click on the details, I have this:

[image]

It just shows me an ID, but that doesn't help me...

I didn't have this problem 2 days ago, but I did a request for a quota extension, so I can create more ingresses, the problem started after they extended the quotas.

To create my ingress, I select one of my services and click on the "Create Ingress" button. I tried with different services but always the same error.

I reported the bug but still don't have an answer, and it's blocking me.

Comment: Ok i found a workaround, instead of using the google cloud interface, just create the ingress with the command line like this : kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if u were not able to create ingress using cloud console,

1- You can create ingress using Cloud shell.

For example, let us consider an example-ingress configuration file manifest which defines an Ingress that sends traffic.

**example-ingress.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hello-world.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

2- Now, create the Ingress object by running the following command:

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/service/networking/example-ingress.yaml
```

Refer to the documentation on [Creating an ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) for more information.

Comment: Hi, this is actually the solution i've found, but thanks for the answer :)